# How to change ExoPlayer subtitle position in android?

Tags: android, exoplayer, subtitle

I'm show subtitle with exoPlayer in my android application. Now I want change position of subtitle from bottom of the screen to the top. I was try `setBottomPaddingFraction` or `setPadding` to the subtitleView but didn't work. Is it possible change subtitle position in screen? If your answer is yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is possible, but you can get exoplayer subtitle with this listener and set it in your textView and put it evry where you want:

```
player.addTextOutput(new TextOutput() {
        @Override
        public void onCues(List<Cue> cues) {

            txtBottomSubtitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            txtBottomSubtitle.setText("");

            if (cues.size() > 0) {
                txtBottomSubtitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
                htmlInTextView(txtBottomSubtitle, cues.get(0).text.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. But how display the contollerView over that textView? Your answer is a trick but not work in my situation.

Comment: I actually use my customControllerView. if you don't find the answer for that you must disable exoplayer contollerView and use your customContollerView